# Pagination for API End points usin will_paginate

Tags: api, pagination, ruby-on-rails-5, will-paginate

I am trying to create an api end point to show a list.
My snippet is

```
def index
  render json: @business, adapter: :json_api
end
```

How can I do pagination for this list?. Is it possible by using only `will_paginate` gem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible using will_paginate gem aslo, either you can use gem 'api-pagination' [click here](https://github.com/davidcelis/api-pagination) for more details,
if you dont want to use this gem then you can manually do something like this,
 you can create a function for page and limit of records per page like this:

```
def page
   params[:page] || 1
end

def limit
  params[:per] || 10
end
```

And then when you fetch your records you can do something like this:

```
def index
  @business = fetch_business.page(page).per(limit)
  render json: @business
end

def fetch_business
  #your code to retrive all business
end
```

And hence you can pass page number on every request which will help you to retrive the data easily.

Since i am begginner into this, comments and suggestions are welcomed.